# DataService that fetches data not loaded already or loads cached values

Tags: javascript, cache, typescript, angular-2+, browser-storage

I load an array from an API that is available throughout the user's whole session. This data is unlikely to change, so it can be cached safely. I have a `DataService` that works like this:

- get `data` from the class property (*scenario: going to a new route*)
- if nothing is there, get `data` from local storage (*scenario: reload*)
- if nothing is there, fetch `data` from API (*scenario: new session*)

This is what I've come up with:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class DataService {
  protected data: Array<any> = null;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData(): Observable<Array<any>> {
    if (this.data === null) {
      this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
  }

  if (this.datas !== null) {
    return of(this.data);
  }

  return this.http.get<Object>(this.url + this.route).pipe(
    retry(3),
    map(response => {
      this.data = response as Array<any>;
      localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(this.data));
      return this.data;
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      this.handleError(error);
      return [];
    })
  );
}
```

The service is registered in the `app.component.ts` and used like this in other components:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/service/data.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.less'],
  providers: []
})

export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  protected subscribers: Subscription[] = [];

  public data: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(public data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscribers.push(
      this.data.getData().subscribe((data) => { this.data = data })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    for (let subscriber of this.subscribers) {
      subscriber.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Is it a good approach? Is this "*the Angular way*"? Can it be improved? Is it readable? Does this indeed increase performance? At least it uses fewer HTTP requests.

<sup>This class is shortened a bit for the review, so don't worry that there's no `handleError` method.</sup>

Comment: _This class is shortened a bit for the review_ - I hope you have a good reason for doing this because we usually don't like shortened code ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t I removed only the `handleError` method, that currently logs to the console  and the assignment of `this.route` and `this.url` which comes from the environment. *Should I add it?* I removed it, because I thought it's not relevant for the review.

Comment: mhmm it looks like it's not such a big deal, this time I'll forgive you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have configured caching headers (both on request and response) correctly, the browser will do caching for you. You can have your code just do the request and the browser will decide whether to pull data from the server or use a cached response. You may need to look up on what your library (i.e. Angular's `HttpClient`) defaults to doing and/or inspect your requests and responses to see if caching is done correctly. Some libraries may disable caching entirely or may require you to explicitly tell it to consider cached results.

If you want to manually cache requests, you might want to look at Angular's [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) class. It works in tandem with `HttpClient` APIs and allows you to write code that sits in between the caller (your code) and the target (the server), allowing you to modify both request and response. You can use this as an intermediary to cache responses as well as cancel requests and return cached responses. One advantage of this approach is you don't have to write a special class that your consumer must know and use. You simply drop in the interceptor and use `HttpClient` APIs as is.

Answer (score 2):

Short review

```
  if (this.datas !== null) {
    return of(this.data);
  }
```

That looks like a bug, should it not be `(this.data !== null)` ?

Also, what is `of`, where is it defined?

Other than, the code is very clean in both parts. So clean, that I almost would switch the `of` and the `localStorage` call. But since this would dupe the null check, that might in the end not be the best idea.

```
  if (this.data !== null) {
    return of(this.data);
  } else {
      this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
      if (this.data !== null) {
        return of(this.data);
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Good catch - luckily it was a just a type, while creating the question. `of` is imported here: `import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';` - it's part of [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html).